# Why is correlation here not 1

Tags: regression

In the image shown, the means of y is 46 and that of x is 73. When x is below its mean, y is below its mean. And when x is above its mean, so is y. So shouldn't the correlation be 1 if they are always in the same direction of the mean?

However r = 0.84 here. How can that be?

[image: Pic]

Comment: The Pearson correlation has magnitude 1 if and only if all points lie on a straiight line with slope not zero. Not the case here.

Comment: The type of correlation you're talking about (based on observations being "above together", and "below together") is a form of *quadrant correlation* sometimes known as the [quadrant count ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrant_count_ratio) - and by a variety of other names. Forms of quadrant correlation based on placing the dividing lines at variable-medians or variable-means have been around for a long time. 

However, these simple measures are different from the Pearson correlation, which is what you're supposed to be looking at here. Start by checking the definition on Wikipedia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not 1 because for a correlation to be 1, each point would have to be equally far from the means of both variables (on a standardized scale). For example, if a point was 3 standard deviations above the mean on X, and 3 standard deviations about the mean on Y, and another point was 2 standard deviations below both means, and another point was 1 standard deviation above both means, etc., then the correlation would be 1. In this example, the points are not equally far from the means of both variables. The data point at (70, 0) is much closer to the X mean than it is to the Y mean (in standardized units).

Comment: But in the correlation formula(https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/2b9c2079a3ffc1aacd36201ea0a3fb2460dc226f) , the only way for the numerator to be less than the denominator is if there instances where they are in opposite directions from their own means right? There is no mention of scale in the formule....

Comment: Apply the formula by hand and see what happens. See what each individual point's contribution to the correlation is by taking $(X_i-\bar{X})(Y_i-\bar{Y})/(s_{X} s_Y)$.